# Active record update attributes without attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model Article. Once it is created we send a activation code to the user with a token.
this activation code is on purpose black listed , so it is not added to the attr_accesible list.

once the user comes back to activate the code

```
articleitem = Article.find_by_activation_code(params[:code])
articleitem.activation_code = ""
```

Now how do we update the record. I don't want to use the save since it activates the before_save methods

I have tried all the below in the controller.

```
articleItem.update(activation_code: "")
update method is private

articleItem.update_attributes(activation_code: "")
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: activation_code
```

What are the other alternatives to update the record

Comment: Sounds like whatever's in your `before_save` methods, probably shouldn't be, if you often want to save without calling them.

Comment: Not quite getting your question. When you want to update an attribute you will end up saving it no matter what options you follow. Save will be called with any of the other methods you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to set a virtual attribute (Untested code)

```
in model

attr_accessor :execute_before_save
before_save :some_method

def some_method
  # Check is execute_before_save is set, if not let the method execute no matter what
  if execute_before_save || true
     # your code follows
  end
end

in your controller

articleitem = Article.find_by_activation_code(params[:code])
articleItem.execute_before_save = false
articleitem.activation_code = ""
articleitem.save
```

That way you control your `before_save` callback but it requires you to set the virtual attribute which is overhead.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I achieved something like this  by using self.new_record?